# python: how to convert json to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Hi I am trying to convert a json file into python DataFrame. Ideally, the columns could be: 
[ideal dataframe format][1]
As the screenshot shows, there is lots of "useless" information that I'd like to discard.
I have tried `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')`
But it turns out to be very far off.
Would appreciate it if you could help out! Thanks a lot!

The json file is as follows:

```
{
  "aspectSet": "article",
  "modelVersion": "1",
  "id": "573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
  "apiUrl": "https://api.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
  "title": {
    "title": "AQR announces job cuts after disappointing 2018"
  },
  "lifecycle": {
    "initialPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z",
    "lastPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z"
  },
  "location": {
    "uri": "https://www.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e"
  },
  "summary": {
    "excerpt": "AQR, the quantitative investment group founded by billionaire Clifford Asness, says it is making “small reductions” to..."
  },
  "editorial": {
    "subheading": "Quantitative investment group’s biggest public funds hit amid market volatility",
    "byline": "Robin Wigglesworth in New York"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `pd.read_json`?

Comment: There's nothing in the screenshot you attached. Can you reattach?

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: sorry I am not allowed to attach anything... the ideal format is one with columns: URI, title, date, summary, subheading. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use json module. 
Try this

```
    import json
    raw_json = {
      "aspectSet": "article",
      "modelVersion": "1",
      "id": "573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
      "apiUrl": "https://api.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
      "title": {
        "title": "AQR announces job cuts after disappointing 2018"
      },
      "lifecycle": {
        "initialPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z",
        "lastPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z"
      },
      "location": {
        "uri": "https://www.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e"
      },
      "summary": {
        "excerpt": "AQR, the quantitative investment group founded by billionaire Clifford Asness, says it is making “small reductions” to..."
      },
      "editorial": {
        "subheading": "Quantitative investment group’s biggest public funds hit amid market volatility",
        "byline": "Robin Wigglesworth in New York"
      }
    }
    object_json = json.dumps(raw_json)
    pd.read_json(object_json)
```

Comment: hey Sam. thank you so much for the codes. but I was expecting a df with columns of URI, title, date, summary, and subheading. best, Darcy

Answer (score 0):

see if [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) works for you :

```
data = {
  "aspectSet": "article",
  "modelVersion": "1",
  "id": "573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
  "apiUrl": "https://api.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e",
  "title": {
    "title": "AQR announces job cuts after disappointing 2018"
  },
  "lifecycle": {
    "initialPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z",
    "lastPublishDateTime": "2019-01-09T00:55:24Z"
  },
  "location": {
    "uri": "https://www.ft.com/content/573abb42-139a-11e9-a581-4ff78404524e"
  },
  "summary": {
    "excerpt": "AQR, the quantitative investment group founded by billionaire Clifford Asness, says it is making “small reductions” to..."
  },
  "editorial": {
    "subheading": "Quantitative investment group’s biggest public funds hit amid market volatility",
    "byline": "Robin Wigglesworth in New York"
  }
}


from pandas import json_normalize
json_normalize(data).filter(regex="Url|title|summary|subheading|Date")
```